# How can I apply a semi-opaque background image to a Google maps polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have a map with some non-filled polygons. The shape of these polygons are imported from a KML file:

```
$(function() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.845188, -0.130463),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var wardsLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('someKMLfile.kml', {
        suppressInfoWindows: true ,
        preserveViewport: true
    });
    wardsLayer.setMap(map);
});
```

What I want to do is fill the polygons defined in the KML file with image files. Is this possible? How?

Bonus question: Is it possible to control the opacity of these background image?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/ProjectedOverlayTest2.html)? The overlays are not arbitrary polygons, they are rectangular (and they don't come from KML, athough that library is used by [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), which does parse KML.

Comment: That's not ideal. Would be difficult to change dynamically, but I could kludge it at a push.